# Check if date overlaps inside array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

I have an array which contains a set of start/end date objects (time included)

i.e.

```
    results["records"] =
[0] -[startDate,endDate]
[1] -[startDate, endDate]
```

I also have another two date objects stored locally as JS variables.
How do I check if these variables i.e. startDateObj && endDateObj OVERLAP with ANY record in the array, by that I mean crossover with any time between and including any start date or end date.

Thank you in advance

Initial attempt below

```
    $(results['records']).each(function() {
console.log('end:' + this[1])
console.log('start:' + this[0])
 if(startDateObj < this[1].end && endDateObj > this[0].start) {
alert('this overlaps')
  }
  });
```

EDIT: Answer added below
Have a great day!

Comment: And what have you already tried? We're not a code-writing service

Comment: `a` and `b` overlap if `a.start < b.end && b.start < a.end`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this structure in your "dateArray" because to check overlaps you need to define a range of date and time.

```
dateArray: [{start: Date, end: Date}];
dateArray.forEach(date => {
  if(startDateObj < date.end && endDateObj > date.start) {
    //this is an overlap
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the full date objects in the array where being treated as a string
so to convert and fix

```
function toDateString(date)
{
            var formatedDate = new Date(date);
            return formatedDate;
}

$(results['records']).each(function() {
 if(startDateObj < toDateString(this[1]) && endDateObj > toDateString(this[0])) 
{
//overlaps
}
```